# How to resolve Skipping acquire of configured file Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, terminal

How do I resolve these issues ? This occurred right after i installed docker......

```
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stablestable/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stablestable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stablestable/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stablestable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stablestable/i18n/Translation-en_IN' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stablestable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stablestable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stablestable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stablestable/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stablestable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stablestable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stablestable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stablestable/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stablestable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stablestable/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stablestable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

My ubuntu is :

```
lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATEEEEE:
i have finally figured it out seems like there were some root complications during installation and as a result i got these issues...
so i uninstalled docker using:

```
 sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

and then I reinstalled Docker using stable scripts:

```
 curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
 DRY_RUN=1 sh ./get-docker.sh
```